# Should private function members be exception safe?

Tags: c++, private-members, private-methods, exception-safety

When writing exception-safe code, should all private member functions guarantee at least basic exception safety? What would be best/good practice in this situation? Alternatives?

For example, say I have a class `Foo` with `public` function member `DoSomething`, which calls `private` function member `DoSomeOfIt`. `DoSomeOfIt` may fail due to some functions that I cannot influence, and when it does it may leave the `Foo` object in a partially modified state which violates `Foo`'s invariants. So I could wrap `DoSomeOfIt` in a `try-catch` block and call another `private` function member `UndoThat` in the `catch` block to undo what `DoSomeOfIt` did. Individually, `DoSomeOfIt` and `UndoThat` may not be exception safe, but `DoSomething` is. Would that be exception safe code? (In this case with strong guarantee)

```cpp
class Foo {
public:
  // I provide strong exception safety guarantee
  void DoSomething() {
    try {
      DoSomeOfIt();
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
      UndoThat();
      throw;
    }
  }
private:
  // I provide no exception safety guarantee.
  DoSomeOfIt() {
    // may throw and violate class invariants.
  }

  // I provide no exception safety guarantee.
  UndoThat() {
    // undoes everything most recent call of
    // DoSomeOfIt did.
  }
};
```

Of course I could simply include the code of `DoSomeOfIt` and `UndoThat` in `DoSomething`, but that could lead to code bloating, and a long function body, whereas breaking up the functions modularizes the tasks and may make the code more readable(?)

DISCLAIMER:
I understand this may be opinion-based. I am not sure if that makes this a bad post, but I'd appreciate any opinions, or experiences where this has lead to issues, or is common practice etc.

Comment: Opinion based - it's a detail of the implementation; the users `Foo` of only care about its public (and protected) interface.  The private implementation can do what it likes, in whatever way it wants to so longs the public contract (including exception guarantees) is fulfilled.

Comment: Anytime I write `catch` in C++, I wonder to myself if RAII would be better. Usually, (not always), I find RAII to be better.  Since you imply that `UndoThat()` can throw exceptions, this is probably a case where RAII is not the best answer, but I thought I'd comment for subsequent readers.  `void DoSomething() {StateSave saveState; DoSomeOfIt(); saveState.setSucceeded();}`

Answer (score 1):

This is my opinion.

If there is a possibility that `DoSomeOfIt` will be used by more than one function, it'll be better to have the exception handling code reside in that function itself -- you don't want to have the exception handling code duplicated across multiple functions. If that is not a possibility, your posted code is fine.

Having said that, if you move the exception handling code to `DoSomething`, you don't lose anything. In fact, the function becomes better. If it is used in the future by another function, the exception handling is already taken care of. Looked at from that point of view, it will be better to move the exception handling code to `DoSomething`.

Comment: I can see the benefit of this. However, `UndoThat` has the same issue. But I guess by this logic, `UndoThat` would only be called by `DoSomeOfIt`, so it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I would personally go stricter and say that `DoSomeOfIt` should _always_ handle the exception handling. There's no telling how it may be used in the future by the next maintainer, and it's an easier mental model to assume that all class invariants are upheld all the time

Comment: @Human-Compiler Of course the whole thing is opinion based, but I'd say this is a tradeoff between the simpler mental model which upholds all class invariants all the time, and possible code-bloat. `DoSomeOfIt` may be a complex function calling other functions and `DoSomething` may be doing a lot more than just `DoSomeOfIt`, perhaps with similar problems. Eventually, I would wonder if the tradeoff would lean towards modularization.